# How to install numpy with pip

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I'm trying to install `numpy` on my Mac.

I'm currently using OS X 10.7.3 and Python version 2.7 (according to `which python`).

I tried `pip install numpy` in the command line and it displayed:

> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement numpy

Do I have to change my Python version?

Comment: Try this link http://scipy.org/install.html

Comment: I tried the method and the responded as : sudo port commend not found....And I changed my .profile's extend by export Path but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get [Mac-ports](http://www.macports.org/) and execute:

`sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose`